# Simple framework using div

Tags: css, html

[image]

Trying to make the above using divs. Each rectangle (one long + the square at its right) should be one unit. Should it be a div inside a div then?.. (I'm obviously new to this so thanks for any help!). The size of the frame should not be fixed but be stretchy..

```
<body>
<div id="frame">
    <div id="div1"></div>           
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
    <div id="div4"></div>
    <div id="divSettings"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

(Made borders of each div in the stylesheet)

Comment: Did you end up resolving your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would make the "frame" div your containing div and set all your other div's using float:right, float"left, br tags, and widht=xx% properties.

Answer (score 0):

I would create [**something like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zmd3N/1/) which uses divs within divs, widths as %, and `float:right` to put the inner divs on the right

```
/* HTML */
<div id="frame">
    <div class='row'><div class='inner'></div></div>
    <div class='row'><div class='inner'></div></div>
    <div class='row'><div class='inner'></div></div>
    <div class='row'><div class='inner'></div></div>
    <div id="divSettings"></div>
</div>

/* CSS */
#frame {
    width: 350px;
    height: 460px;
}
.row {
    height:100px;
    width: 100%;
}
.inner {
    float: right;
    width: 33%;
    height:100%;
    border-left:1px solid black;
}
#divSettings {
    height: 50px;
    width:100%;
}
div:not(.inner) {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Note: When setting the height of `frame`, don't forget to include the added height that the borders on the top and bottom that the inner divs have

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6bSZM/)

```
<div class="left" style="float:left; width:70%">
    <div class="left1">left 1</div>
    <div class="left1">left 2</div>
    <div class="left1">left 3</div> 
</div>

<div class="right" style="float:right; width:30%">
<div class="right1">right 1</div>
    <div class="right1">right 2</div>
    <div class="right1"> right3</div> 
</div>
<div class="footer" style="clear:both;">footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/Y6UCr/)**

With this way we create rows and have our two divs into this row.

There is also another way which we have all the divs positioned relatively inside a `div` container:

**[EXAMPLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/Y6UCr/1/)**

Now it's up to you to decide what's better for you to use...